Domain of a Jacobi operator with unbounded coefficients
Is it possible to describe the domain of a Jacobi operator explicitly?
Let $J$ be the linear operator acting on a real sequence $(u_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ by
$$
J(u_{n}) = a_{n+1} u_{n+1} + a_{n} u_{n-1}
$$
where  the $a_{n}$'s are fixed positive coefficients, obeying to $a_{n} \sim c n^{\alpha}$, with $c>0$ and $0<\alpha<1$.
I am interested in describing explicitly the maximal domain  $D(J)$ where $J$ can be defined from $D(J)$ to $l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$. Hence, I would like to know the sequences $(u_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ for which $(J(u_{n}))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$.
It is easy to show that if
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} u_{n}^{2} n^{2\alpha} < \infty
$$
then $(J(u_{n}))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$. Is the converse true? Are there any sequence alternating between positve and negative number for which $(J(u_{n}))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ but
$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} u_{n}^{2} n^{2\alpha} = \infty
$ ?
Moreover, I wonder if  $u_{n} n^{\alpha}$ is necessarily bounded if $(J(u_{n}))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$.
